Problem with pyspark mapping - Index out of range after split
When trying to map our 6 column pyspark RDD into a 4d-tuple we get a list out of range error for any list element besides 0 which return the normal result.
The dataset is structured like this:
X,Y,FID,DIVISION,LOCATION,PREC
-118.289241553,33.7576608970001,1,HARBOR,2175 JOHN S. GIBSON BLVD.,5
-118.275394206,33.9386273800001,2,SOUTHEAST,145 W. 108TH ST.,18
-118.277669655,33.9703073800001,3,77TH STREET,7600 S. BROADWAY,12
-118.419841576,33.9916553210001,4,PACIFIC,12312 CULVER BLVD.,14
-118.305141563,34.0105753400001,5,SOUTHWEST,1546 MARTIN LUTHER KING JR. BLVD.,3
-118.256118891,34.012355905,6,NEWTON,3400 S. CENTRAL AVE.,13
-118.247294123,34.0440195,7,CENTRAL,251 E. 6TH ST.,1
-118.450779541,34.0437774120001,8,WEST LOS ANGELES,1663 BUTLER AVE.,8
-118.213067956,34.045008769,9,HOLLENBECK,2111 E. 1ST ST.,4
-118.342829525,34.046747682,10,WILSHIRE,4861 VENICE BLVD.,7
-118.291175911,34.050208529,11,OLYMPIC,1130 S. VERMONT AVE.,20
-118.266979649,34.056690437,12,RAMPART,1401 W. 6TH ST.,2
-118.33066931,34.095833225,13,HOLLYWOOD,1358 N. WILCOX AVE.,6
-118.249414484,34.119200666,14,NORTHEAST,3353 SAN FERNANDO RD.,11
-118.385859348,34.1716939300001,15,NORTH HOLLYWOOD,11640 BURBANK BLVD.,15
-118.445225709,34.1837432730001,16,VAN NUYS, 6240 SYLMAR AVE.,9
-118.547454438,34.193397227,17,WEST VALLEY,19020 VANOWEN ST.,10
-118.599636542,34.221376654,18,TOPANGA,21501 SCHOENBORN ST.,21
-118.410417183,34.2530912220001,19,FOOTHILL,12760 OSBORNE ST.,16
-118.531373363,34.256969059,20,DEVONSHIRE,10250 ETIWANDA AVE.,17
-118.468197808,34.272979397,21,MISSION,11121 N. SEPULVEDA BLVD.,19

rdd3 = sc.textFile('hdfs://path/data.csv')

header3 = rdd3.first()
rdd3 = rdd3.filter(lambda line: line!=header3)\
       .map(lambda row: row.split(","))\
       .map(lambda row: (row[0],row[1],row[3],row[5])) \
       .collect()

For example if we only keep row[0] there is no error but if we keep row[1] it throws a list out of range exception. It's like the row.split(",") does not return a 6 element list, which it should.
This is the exception 
Any ideas?

Given the example I wasn't able to reproduce the issue, it gave me the correct output. Do you run the actual provided code?

Ok got it, it's because of the blank line after the first row.

I provided the full dataset in the edit, can you still reproduce it?

It looks like the problem you are trying to solve is better solved with dataframes interface:
df = spark_session.read.csv('hdfs://path/data.csv', header=True)

res = df.select('X', 'Y', 'DIVISION', 'PREC').collect()

EDIT:
If using rdds is mandatory you should ignore the blank line after the header line.

It's an assignment and using RDDs is mandatory...

@Toxicone7 ok see the comment to the original post

@bussfighter The line doesn't exist in the dataset, I just can't put it all in the stackoverflow editor

@Toxicone7 the only thing that could lead to such an exception is a line without commas so you have to check if there is either a blank line or a line separated not by commas in your dataset.

turns out the wrong file was in the HDFS... all good now
